# Using OpenCV in node.js to rotate images

Tags: node.js, opencv

I have around 200,000 images that need to be rotated correctly.
Also, 30 images with their corresponding rotated images, how will I train opencv to achieve what I want? Some tips would be appreciated.
I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv) library for [opencv](http://opencv.org)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open each file using the `readImage` method as per their examples and the Matrix your callback receives has a `rotate` function you can use.

Comment: Ok but I need it to detect how many degrees the picture should rotate